# Как удалить 11 символов внутри имени файла в python?

Tags: python-3.x

Я хочу удалить 11 символов в названии каждого файла внутри каталога. Например, имя файла Frazer\ Campbell\ -\ Mr\ Green\'s\ Envy\ (Original\ Mix)-EIBSvv7psME.mp3 и мне нужно удалить 11 символов в конце имени, перед расширением, чтобы в итоге получилось Frazer\ Campbell\ -\ Mr\ Green\'s\ Envy\ (Original\ Mix).mp3

Какой в общих чертах алгоритм выполнения этой задачи с использованием python и какие модули нужно использовать?

Comment: Использовать модуль `os`. Получить список файлов в каталоге, обойти список, изменить на каждой итерации строку имени файла и переименовать файл.

Comment: Спасибо, Сергей!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот пример, как можно реализовать изменение имён файлов

```
import glob
import os

FILES_EXT = '.txt'
PATH_NAME = 'files/**/*' + FILES_EXT


# override this function for you fileName
def getnfn(oldFileName):
    # >>> x = "Hello World!"
    # >>> x[2:]
    # 'llo World!'
    return oldFileName[1::]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for filePath in glob.iglob(PATH_NAME, recursive=True):
        print(filePath)
        path = filePath.rsplit('\\', 1)[0]
        fileName = filePath.split('.')[0].rsplit('\\')[-1]
        os.rename(filePath, path + '\\' + getnfn(fileName) + FILES_EXT)
```

До выполнения скрипта:
[image: До выполнения скрипта]

После выполнения скрипта:
[image: После выполнения скрипта]

Можно указать своё имя файла, переопределив функцию

```
# override this function for you fileName
def getnfn(oldFileName):
    # >>> x = "Hello World!"
    # >>> x[2:]
    # 'llo World!'
    return oldFileName[1::]
```

Comment: Спасибо, Никита!